# Using localStorage to store numerical value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use `localStorage` to hold the value of the players health in an HTML5 based game, and when the HP value is below 0, nothing happens.

```
<!--Calling Statement-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="../S5/S5.html" onclick="alterHP(-3);"
        class="ghost-button">Go on to the next scene</a></li>
</ul>
```

in a separate .js file

```
function declareHP() {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("HP", "20");
    } else {
        /*Can't Store, Oh well*/
    }
}

function alterHP(value) {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        var currentHP = parseInt(localStorage.HP);
        localStorage.HP = currentHP + value;
        if (!(parseInt(localStorage.HP) > 0)) {
            window.location.assign('../youLose.html');          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think happens the first time your function is called, when `localStorage.HP` doesn't yet exist?

Comment: may be changing like this `localStorage.getItem("HP")` will be solve

Comment: @LGSon Sorry, I completely forgot about this. I have no idea what was happening, it was odd. I switched to php, it was simpler. Your solution works fine most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the line

```
var currentHP = parseInt(localStorage.HP);
```

to

```
var currentHP = localStorage.HP ? parseInt(localStorage.HP) : 0;
```

it will work

---

And you could do like this

```
function alterHP(value) {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.HP = (localStorage.HP ? parseInt(localStorage.HP) : 0) + value;
        if (!(parseInt(localStorage.HP) > 0)) {
            window.location.assign('../youLose.html');          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setterfunc(targetedelement, presetting) {
    if(localStorage.getItem(targetedelement) == undefined) {
        localStorage.setItem(targetedelement, presetting);
    }
}
setterfunc('HP', 0);
```

Now you can run your script ,based on the comment you haven't initialize the value localStorage.HP for the initial use.Now you can run your script.

```
/*Function*/
function alterHP(value) {
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        var currentHP = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("HP"));
        localStorage.setItem("HP", currentHP + value);
        if (!(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("HP") > 0)) {
            window.location.assign('../youLose.html');          
        }
    }
}
```